# How to get value of a memory address using command?

Tags: linux, command-line, memory, command, dd

At the memory address, `0x7fffffffeb58` of a program lies a value, I want to find out the value of the address.

Is there a way to get the value just by using commands?

I've tried `dd` but to no avail.

Comment: Can you give more context as to what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am doing a CTF challenge and the hint tells me that i have to find a way to read a memory address (0x7fffffffeb58) of a ELF file/program and it will give me the value of an unsigned int.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To peek at memory addresses of a process, you can look at `/proc/$pid/mem`. See also `/proc/$pid/maps` for what's mapped in the process' address space.

You'll want to `seek()` within that file to the location you want, which you should be able to do with `dd`:

```
dd bs=1 skip="$((0x7fffffffeb58))" count=4 if="/proc/$pid/mem" |
  od -An -vtu4
```

Would read 4 bytes at that address and interpret them as an unsigned 32 bit integer.

Another approach is to attach a debugger to the process:

```
gdb --batch -ex 'x/u 0x7fffffffeb58' -p "$pid"
```

In any case, note that depending on the value of the `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope` sysctl, you may need to have superuser privileges to do that.

Comment: I tried to find the pid of my program using px ax but i found out that the process ID kept on changing and it is not inside proc/ folder. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: @suppko you could try containing your process inside a cgroup, and then just access the pid in the cgroup `cgcreate -g memory` to create a cgroup, `cgexec --sticky` to start the process in the cgroup created, and `cat /path/to/cgroup/cgroup.procs` to get pids.

Comment: @suppko, you could start by suspending those processes (`killall -STOP process_name`) which would give you all the time you need to look at their memory.

Answer (score 9):

**If you want to access virtual memory of a specific process:** refer to @Stéphane's answer.

**If you want to access physical memory:**

If you have `devmem` installed:

```
devmem 0x2000000
```

Alternative approach with hexdump:

```
hexdump -C --skip 0x7fffffffeb58 /dev/mem | head
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47715109/read-a-specific-memory-address-via-dev-mem-from-the-command-line) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Note that there's a difference between *virtual* memory addresses which belong to a certain process, and *physical* memory addresses which you can access via `/dev/mem`. The OP likely meant a virtual address ("of a program" suggests this, though he didn't specify exactly).

Comment: I think you are right. I've added some explanation.

Comment: @rudib the Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS I am accessing has neither `devmem` nor `hexdump`, any other idea how to read a physical address ?

Comment: @AxelBregnsbo a simple approach should be to dump the whole memory into a file and use `hexdump` on another machine. `cat /dev/mem > yourfile` should work. But i haven't tried it.

Comment: hexdump: invalid option -- '-'